# Javascript creating an onclick event for a dynamic table row

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble attaching an onclick event to my dynamic table rows.

What I have is here:

```
function parseOrderLine(data) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    if (obj.length > 0) {
        var tbl = document.createElement('table');
        var row = tbl.insertRow(0);
        var cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.innerHTML = "Code";
        cell = row.insertCell(1);
        cell.innerHTML = "Size";
        cell = row.insertCell(2);
        cell.innerHTML = "Description";
        cell = row.insertCell(3);
        cell.innerHTML = "Type";
        cell = row.insertCell(4);
        cell.innerHTML = "Price";
        cell.style.textAlign = "right";
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            row = tbl.insertRow(i + 1);
            row.className = "results_row";
            cell = row.insertCell(0);
            cell.innerHTML = obj[i].Code;
            cell = row.insertCell(1);
            cell.innerHTML = obj[i].Size;
            cell = row.insertCell(2);
            cell.innerHTML = obj[i].Description;
            cell = row.insertCell(3);
            cell.innerHTML = obj[i].Type;
            cell = row.insertCell(4);
            cell.innerHTML = parseFloat(obj[i].Price).toFixed(2);
            cell.style.textAlign = "right";
            //row.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert('listen'); });
            row.onclick = (function(){ alert('click'); });
        }
        return tbl.outerHTML;
    }
    else { ...
```

As you can see I have tried both setting the onclick event and adding a listener. Neither seem to work.

I'm hoping someone can tell me I'm just being crazy and have overlooked something obvious.  ;0)

Any help appreciated guys.

Thanks for reading.

Jas

Comment: It could be something to do with you returning the outerHTML rather than the element. Appending the table to the page inside that function could also work, I suspect.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed. Fixed now. Explained by @Luizgrs below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is on the `tbl.outerHTML`.

When you add an event listener using `addEventListener`, Javascript does not add the method to your HTML code in the `onclick` attribute, it is added only to the DOM. So when you use `tbl.outerHTML` you listener isn't added to the returned HTML code. The same is applicable for the `row.onclick = function()...`

If you want to keep the event listener when using `outerHTML` I suggest you go with `setAttribute`:

```js
function createTable()
{
        var obj = [1,2,3,4,5];
        var tbl = document.createElement('table');
        var row = tbl.insertRow(0);
        var cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.innerHTML = "Code";
        cell = row.insertCell(1);
        cell.innerHTML = "Size";
        cell = row.insertCell(2);
        cell.innerHTML = "Description";
        cell = row.insertCell(3);
        cell.innerHTML = "Type";
        cell = row.insertCell(4);
        cell.innerHTML = "Price";
        cell.style.textAlign = "right";
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            row = tbl.insertRow(i + 1);
            row.className = "results_row";
            cell = row.insertCell(0);
            cell.innerHTML = obj[i].Code;
            cell = row.insertCell(1);
            cell.innerHTML = obj[i].Size;
            cell = row.insertCell(2);
            cell.innerHTML = obj[i].Description;
            cell = row.insertCell(3);
            cell.innerHTML = obj[i].Type;
            cell = row.insertCell(4);
            cell.innerHTML = parseFloat(obj[i].Price).toFixed(2);
            cell.style.textAlign = "right";
            //row.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert('listen'); });
            row.setAttribute('onclick', "(function(){ alert('click'); })()");
        }
        return tbl.outerHTML;
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = createTable();
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

HOWEVER it's not the best solution, you should not use `outerHTML` when you want in fact use the object you just created (in your case, the table). You should add it in the DOM using the `appendChild` method, doing this way you can use `addEventListener`:

```js
function createTable()
{
        var obj = [1,2,3,4,5];
        var tbl = document.createElement('table');
        var row = tbl.insertRow(0);
        var cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.innerHTML = "Code";
        cell = row.insertCell(1);
        cell.innerHTML = "Size";
        cell = row.insertCell(2);
        cell.innerHTML = "Description";
        cell = row.insertCell(3);
        cell.innerHTML = "Type";
        cell = row.insertCell(4);
        cell.innerHTML = "Price";
        cell.style.textAlign = "right";
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            row = tbl.insertRow(i + 1);
            row.className = "results_row";
            cell = row.insertCell(0);
            cell.innerHTML = obj[i].Code;
            cell = row.insertCell(1);
            cell.innerHTML = obj[i].Size;
            cell = row.insertCell(2);
            cell.innerHTML = obj[i].Description;
            cell = row.insertCell(3);
            cell.innerHTML = obj[i].Type;
            cell = row.insertCell(4);
            cell.innerHTML = parseFloat(obj[i].Price).toFixed(2);
            cell.style.textAlign = "right";
            row.addEventListener("click", (function(){ alert('click'); }));
        }
        return tbl;
}

document.getElementById('test').appendChild(createTable());
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, should have realised that. Solution works a treat. :)

Comment: sorry, new to this, wasn't sure how ;)

Comment: wouldnt it be simple to add the row in this way.    `$("#table tbody").append('<tr id="' + data[i]["data1"] + '"><td>' + data[i]["data1"] + '</td><td>' + data[i]["data2"] + '</td></tr>');`

Comment: $("#table tbody") is not javascript  ;)